# Cleanup /pipeline folder after docker-push

Tags: wercker

I've created some wercker pipelines with "build" and "docker" pipeline. Both pipelines use different boxes. The "docker" pipeline copies the compiled code from $WERCKER_SOURCE_DIR/target to the correct folders and the last step is a internal/docker-push.
When I inspect the resulting docker image I still see all the sources in the /pipeline/source folder within the resulting image.

I've tried to do a script step with `rm -rf /pipeline` after the docker-push, but after inspection the /pipeline (and all sources, build cache, scripts) are still part of the resulting image.

Is there any way to clean this and create a cleaner image (I just want my compiled code in the image).

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the step to remove the /pipeline folder before the internal/docker-push step, and this works out fine.